# Intel CPU: Core 2 Duo vs. Xeon Dual Core. Which is faster?

Tags: cpu, microsoft-virtual-pc, intel-core2, xeon

1. Xeon: Dual Core Intel Xeon W3503 2.40 GHz, 4M L3, 4.8GT/s
2. Intel® Core2 Duo E8400 (6MB, 3.0 GHz, 1333FSB),

USES:
Virtual PC (and doing software development within Virtual PC)
A little bit of video editing
Desktop software (like Outlook, Quickbooks, etc.)

I think #1 is faster, but wanted feedback from other folks here.

Which is faster and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SPEC](http://www.spec.org) is always a good reference for this kind of thing.  [Here are their data for those two CPUs](http://www.spec.org/cgi-bin/osgresults?conf=cpu2006&op=fetch&proj-COMPANY=256&proj-SYSTEM=256&proj-PEAK=256&proj-BASE=256&proj-CORES=256&proj-CHIPS=256&proj-CORESCHP=0&proj-THREADS=256&proj-CPU=256&critop-CPU=0&crit-CPU=W3505|E8400&proj-CPU_MHZ=256&proj-CPUCHAR=0&proj-NCPUORD=0&proj-PARALLEL=0&proj-BASEPTR=0&proj-PEAKPTR=0&proj-CACHE1=0&proj-CACHE2=0&proj-CACHE3=0&proj-OCACHE=0&proj-MEMORY=0&proj-OS=0&proj-FS=0&proj-COMPILER=0&proj-HWAVAIL=0&crit2-HWAVAIL=Jan&proj-SWAVAIL=0&crit2-SWAVAIL=Jan&proj-LICENSE=0&proj-TESTER=0&proj-SPONSOR=0&proj-TESTDAT=0&crit2-TESTDAT=Jan&proj-PUBLISH=256&crit2-PUBLISH=Jan&proj-UPDATE=0&crit2-UPDATE=Jan&dups=0&duplist=COMPANY&duplist=SYSTEM&duplist=CORES&duplist=CHIPS&duplist=CORESCHP&duplist=THREADS&duplist=CPU&duplist=PARALLEL&duplist=BASEPTR&duplist=PEAKPTR&duplist=CACHE1&duplist=CACHE2&duplist=CACHE3&duplist=OCACHE&dupkey=PUBLISH&latest=Dec-9999&sort1=CPU&sdir1=1&sort2=SYSTEM&sdir2=1&sort3=CORESCHP&sdir3=-1&format=tab).

SPEC's result numbers are a ratio of the performance of the system to that of a Sun Ultra Enterprise 2.  Roughly, the computer tested is "result" times faster than a UE2.  Since all computers are referenced from that one benchmark, you can divide the results from two different computers and find their relative performances.

The CINT benchmark is integer-math based and the CFP benchmark is floating-point based.  The "Rate" benchmarks test a fully loaded system and the non-"Rate", "Speed", benchmarks test a single process.  That is, how fast can it do one thing versus how fast can it do a bunch of things at once.

You can find more data about SPEC's benchmarks on their web site, including information on the [CPU2006](http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/) benchmark.

The Xeon is slightly faster, despite its slower clock speed.  This is probably due to the Xeon's on-die memory controller, and the fact that it has HyperThreading, as shown by the fact that its "Rate" benchmarks show a greater improvement over the Core2 than the "Speed" benchmarks.

Comment: Any idea what "Result" is measured in?

The Xeon (admittedly the slightly faster 2.5 Ghz) was 50% higher in "Result".

(Intel Core 2 Duo E8400, 3 Ghz)    30.9    29.5   2   1   
CELSIUS M470, Intel Xeon W3505 (2.5 Ghz)   47.4  45.9  2  1

Comment: I've updated my answer to flesh out what the SPEC results mean.

Answer (score 0):

Ehh, probably the Xeon... the Xeons that start with a 3 are basically not that much better than a standard desktop version with a similar clock speed (but sometimes support additional features, motherboard permitting).

I would have to say the Xeon as it looks like that you are basically comparing a Core I7 against a Core 2 Duo.